# Is it possible to programatically sign into a google account with Javascript/HTML?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, automation, automated-tests

I have a question today that the google docs were not seeming to answer for me.  My scenario is that I am writing a set of tests for my company's app, one of which is to sign into accounts on our app programatically so that I can then test core functionality on our platform.

The thing that currently has me stumped is trying to sign into a google account programatically.  From our app, I can programatically click the sign-in button that will redirect the browser to the sign-in page for google, but once on that page I can't seem to insert credentials into the username and password fields (or trigger the submit button) with javascript / HTML.

Is there a way to do this, maybe using a google API?

For your reference, I was looking at the following pages and did not find an answer, though maybe I just missed something?

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/javascript-flow
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/reference

As a final note, I'll be looking to programatically sign into facebook as well after I figure out how to do it with google.  If anyone knows how to do this, I'd appreciate some details.  Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of you having to redirect users to Google's homepage is to prevent exploits which are possible when the whole Oauth2 authentication procedure is automatic. It would be possible either if Google+ would allow you to setup sandbox users which allow a less secure login flow (I'm not aware of any such), or if you find some hacky way of go around their security.

That doesn't mean that you cannot write integration tests, however. Most Oauth2 applications allow you to request long-lived Oauth2 tokens (30 days or more), which you can save to a file and use whenever you run your integration tests. You would have to manually login whenever it expires, but that shouldn't be a big issue.

You can read all about Oauth2 here https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2.